# Plotting time with matplotlib: TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, matplotlib, time, typeerror

G'morning all!

Could somebody help me with the following problem? Thank you in advance!

I have a CSV file with time-stamps (hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds) and brightness of an object in magnitudes (float), like this:

```
16,59,55,51 13.8
17,00,17,27 13.7
17,00,39,01 13.6
17,01,01,06 13.4
```

And here is my python script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from datetime import time

x = []
y = []

with open('calibrated.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(time(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', label='brightness')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('time [UT]')
plt.ylabel('brightness [mag, CR]')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

When I run the script, I get this TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lightcurve.py", line 11, in 
    x.append(time(row[0]))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to split the `row` first by the space to separate time from data. Then you need to split the first part of it again by `,` to obtain the hours, minutes etc.

Comment: csv.reader returns lists of str's, time is expecting int's.

Comment: I have deleted the "update" part of this question since your other question which is about the new error you received has now been solved. Otherwise it might be confusing to other people coming to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happens because you are passing *strings* to [`datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) which requires integers

If we look at `row[0]`, the result will be `"16,59,55,51"`. So, this string has to be split up using `row[0].split(",")` which creates a list of strings. The contents of this list needs to be converted to integers using `int()`, and can then be passed to the `datetime.time` function.

Your code will become:

```
x = []
y = []

with open('calibrated.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in plots:
        hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds = [int(s) for s in row[0].split(",")]

        x.append(time(hours,minutes,seconds,milliseconds))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', label='brightness')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel('time [UT]')
plt.ylabel('brightness [mag, CR]')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: David, do you have any idea about my new TypeError described in the update section of my question?

Comment: @SergiusPro The example csv data you have provided. Is that _exactly_ the format that the csv takes?

Comment: Yes, absolutely the same.

Comment: Hmm, what numpy and matplotlib versions are you using?

Comment: numpy: '1.13.3' and matplotlib: '1.5.1'

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the error. I am using matplotlib 2.1.1. so it could be something they changed when updating matplotlib

Comment: Hm, strange, I've just updated numpy to 1.14.0 and matplotlib to 2.1.1, but still the same TypeError. I am stuck...

Comment: I'm tempted to say that you could ask another question (as techincally your initial problem was solved) becuase I'm afraid I am also stuck!

Comment: @DavidG Hello, I need help with my question on Matplotlib. Can you help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855010/matplotlib-typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number

Answer (score 0):

Your row[0] is a string of numbers separated by commas, e.g. "16,59,55,51".

You'll need to split them into subfields, and then convert each of the smaller numeric strings to actual integers, e.g.:

`(hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds) = [int(v) for v in row[0].split(',')]
x.append(time(hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds))`

Answer (score 0):

When you scan in the CSV file your row data contains a string in row[0]. For example, the first line of your csv file becomes:

```
row = ["16,59,55,51", "13.8"]
```

To fix this, you need to convert those strings to appropriate values.

```
 with open('calibrated.csv','r') as csvfile:
        plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for row in plots:
            t = [int(x) for x in row[0].split(',')]
            x.append(time(t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3]))
            y.append(float(row[1])
```

Another option is to use the datetime stamp like so:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = []
y = []

with open('calibrated.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(datetime.strptime(row[0], '%H,%M,%S,%f'))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
```

This will use your milliseconds as microseconds, but that doesn't seem like it's a very big deal to me. It does, however, allow you to add dates later if you need to.